# How do I make diff-mode display whitespace similar to other programming modes?

Tags: emacs

When I enable `whitespace-mode` with added whitespace options:

```
(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (setq-local whitespace-style
                                        '(face
                                          tabs
                                          spaces
                                          wspaces
                                          trailing
                                          indentation::space
                                          indentation::tab
                                          newline))
                            (whitespace-mode 1)))
```

But I do not get the appearance similar to in programming modes, but instead just colors to represent different types of whitespace and it looks unpleasant. Is there a way to make it look like in programming modes?

Comment: What's the relation between your question and `diff-mode`? Your question is not very clear, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`space-mark` defaults to a middle-dot (Unicode \u00B7 `·`) -- *"SPACEs and HARD SPACEs are visualized via display table.*"  `wspaces` is *not* a valid setting -- thus, substitute `wspaces` with `space-mark`.

The original poster may also be interested in visualizing tabs with `tab-mark` (Unicode \u00BB `»`); and hard returns with `newline-mark` (i.e., the dollar sign `$`).  They are both visualized via the display table.

```
(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (setq-local whitespace-style
                                        '(face
                                          tabs
                                          tab-mark
                                          spaces
                                          space-mark
                                          trailing
                                          indentation::space
                                          indentation::tab
                                          newline
                                          newline-mark))
                            (whitespace-mode 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No idea what you mean by *make it look like in programming modes*. You might want to explain that or give an example.
2. Library [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight-chars.el) gives you more flexibility wrt how you indicate whitespace (and other chars). See [Highlight Chars](http://www.emacswiki.org/ShowWhiteSpace#HighlightChars). You can pretty much do whatever you like. (But see #1: better describe what you actually want.)

Comment: I want it to display spaces as `.` characters and tabs as `>>` characters and pretty much lawlist answered it. But I may give you package a try. Thanks.